# Application has stopped unexpectedly please try again Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The application has stopped unexpectedly : mrsnakey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312250/the-application-has-stopped-unexpectedly-mrsnakey)

Hello guys I am very new to programming and recently borrowed the book Beginning Android Games by Mario Zechner. He taught me how to create a game named mr nom. I followed every single instruction and renamed mr nom to mrsnakey.

My logcat error is as follows:

```
 04-25 08:37:16.422: I/Process(856): Sending signal. PID: 856 SIG: 9
04-25 08:39:58.712: W/dalvikvm(863): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/zardtechnologies/mrsnakey/MrSnakey; (15)
04-25 08:39:58.752: W/dalvikvm(863): Link of class 'Lcom/zardtechnologies/mrsnakey/MrSnakey;' failed
04-25 08:39:58.752: D/AndroidRuntime(863): Shutting down VM
04-25 08:39:58.752: W/dalvikvm(863): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey/com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey.MrSnakey}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey.MrSnakey in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey-2.apk]
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey.MrSnakey in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey-2.apk]
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-25 08:39:58.792: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  ... 11 more
```

My manifest is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Mr.Snakey" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MrSnakey"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="Mr.Snakey"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="12" />

</manifest>
```

My Activity is here:

```
package com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey;

import com.zardapps.framework.Screen;
import com.zardtechnologies.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGame;

public class MrSnakey extends AndroidGame {

    public Screen getStartScreen() {
        return new LoadingScreen(this);
    }




}
```

**My AndroidGame file**

```
package com.zardtechnologies.androidgames.framework.impl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.zardapps.framework.Audio;
import com.zardapps.framework.FileIO;
import com.zardapps.framework.Game;
import com.zardapps.framework.Graphics;
import com.zardapps.framework.Input;
import com.zardapps.framework.Screen;

public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 480 : 320;
        int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 320 : 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getStartScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "GLGAME");

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
        screen.resume();
        renderView.resume();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();
        renderView.pause();
        screen.pause();

        if (isFinishing())
            screen.dispose();
    }

    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        return graphics;
    }

    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");
        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
}
```

Oh another note i searched the web and many people said to debug .I debugged it and I got this:

```
Mr.Snakey [Android Application] 
    DalvikVM[localhost:8631]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2585  
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679   
            ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033  
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Looper.loop() line: 123 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
        Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Any tips on how to read this? only

```
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  

                ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
```

only these gave me a box that says "attach sources"

Thanks for reading!
Appreciate any help given :)

Comment: You are missing the class com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey.MrSnakey, are you sure it's included in the built .apk ?

Comment: yea i have a MrSnakey.java file its a class

Comment: is your MrSnakey.java file in the com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey package in the source tree because I see your main activity is in com.zardtechnologies.androidgames.framework.impl

Comment: yea my MrSnakey.java is in com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey 
however, my AndroidGame file is in  com.zardtechnologies.androidgames.framework.impl

Comment: without looking at the whole project it looks like it can't resolve the extension class. You might try to combine everything into one package or use the whole path name instead of just the .MrSnarkey in the manifest so you would use com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey.MrSnarkey though I don't think that will solve it.  Also do a clean before build if you try any of this.

Comment: so how do i go about it? any ways to help u get noe what is the problem with my project?

Comment: Well if you tried all of the above with no joy then it's probably something simple, if it's a eclipse project and you have a place to zip and upload the whole project I can take a look.

Comment: Please don't re-post questions that have been closed. Rather, edit the original and flag for them to be reviewed by a moderator. I'm taking a look at your previous question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/zardtechnologies/mrsnakey/MrSnakey; (15)
```

This is the key thing why your app is failing.

I would suggest move AndroidGame and Game both classes into same package as MrSnakey (com.zardtechnologies.mrsnakey) and try. Some how Dalvik unable to link your super class while loading MrSnakey.

Comment: how do i move both classes into the same package? beginner here ;X

Comment: Copy those classes to mrsnakey package and delete them from existing package. Take a backup of your work.

Comment: i copied but i still get errors